# How do I make the main page be the blog page and not a separate "home" page?

Tags: homepage, blog

If you go to www.TwistedTalesOfTimmy.com you will be at the main page. It is a web comic strip with Comic Easel installed. You can get back to this page anytime you click the logo at the top.

However, if you click HOME in the menu, it takes you to a separate home page. I want the main page to be the home page. Additionally, I'm trying to make this home page the blog page as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible settings for this in WordPress.

**Option A**

Your front page (http://twistedtalesoftimmy.com/) is **dynamic** and shows the latest blog posts.

**Option B**

Your front page (http://twistedtalesoftimmy.com/) is **static** and points to a regular page in WordPress.

There is another page (e.g. http://twistedtalesoftimmy.com/blog/) that shows the latest blog posts.

---

You can switch between both options under Settings -> Reading in your WordPress admin:

[image]

Choose what's right for you.

After that, you can edit the navigation menu under Appearance -> Menus or Appearance -> Customize to make sure the "Home" link really points to the home page (front page).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried this first but it didn't work, possibly because I have the Comic Easel plug-in. I did a work around though: I made a link that takes me to the main page and called it HOME. This works but can you see any potential downsides to this that I might not forsee?

Comment: There's no downside to that as it's a perfectly valid way to add such a link. In fact, it's the only way to create a link to the front page. Glad you could resolve the issue. If you don't mind, could you mark this answer as accepted?